# Sort an Arraylist which contains 3 lists linked to each other

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList which contains 3 lists. The first contains String, the secound integer and the thrid float.
First value of each list is related to each other, secound and so on.

```
List<List> calculation = new ArrayList<List>();
ArrayList<String>candidate = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> frequency = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Float> score = new ArrayList<Float>();
calculation.add(candidate);
calculation.add(frequency);
calculation.add(score);
```

Now I would like to sort the double list (in ascending or descending order) and of course the values in the other two lists should be change with the sorting of the third list.

How can i do this? Maybe my construct (Arraylist containing three lists) is not the best way. I'm also often for other apparoaches ;)

Comment: Why not create a class that contains candidate, frequency and score, and sort a single ArrayList of that class?

Comment: You can sort all of them instead of only score, for exemple, when you do the sorting inside your nested for loop you can simpli swap also the values in the other Arrays instead of only the one in yours, if you need I can give you a more detailed answer

Comment: I was already thinking about this, but I would like to use some existing sorting function ;) I think in your suggestion, I would have to write my own sorting method or override an existing...

Answer (score 0):

You need an overarching data structure to maintain cohesion as the lists are reordered.

Personally I would move them into a list of Apache [Triple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Triple.html) and then you can define a Comparator or similar over that.

Answer (score 0):

I choose the way with a extra class. Works fine, thanks guys!

```
public class Result {

    String candidate;
    int frequency;
    double score;

    public Result (String candidate, int frequency, double score){
        this.candidate=candidate;
        this.frequency=frequency;
        this.score=score;
    }
}
```